# Intercepting anchor links for mx html component in flex

Tags: apache-flex, adobe

I have a html page loaded in the mx htmlcomponent. The hmtl page contains some links and I have to intercept those links and decide whether to open it in system default browser or let the htmlComponent handle it.

For now I am able to get the href on flex side but not sure of how to pass it back to the htmlComponent if I dont want to process it.

Is there any way to accomplish this?

Thanks in advance